# Mocking Axios and Reusing Mocks Across Test Files in Vitest

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, vitest

I am facing an issue when trying to mock Axios for my tests and reusing these mocks across different test files. The primary goal is to mock Axios utilizing **`vi.mock`** from **`vitest`**, but an error is thrown, hindering the process. The error message displayed is: **`Error: Parse failure: Unexpected token (20:0)`** pinpointing to a particular line in the **`mockAxios.ts`** file.

```
// mockAxios.ts
import { vi } from "vitest";

export const mocks = vi.hoisted(() => ({
    get: vi.fn(),
}));

vi.mock('axios', async () => {
    const actual: any = await vi.importActual("axios");
    return {
        default: {
            ...actual.default,
            create: vi.fn(() => ({
                ...actual.default.create(),
                get: mocks.get,  
            })),
        },
    };
});  // This is line 20
```

I have used vi.mock to mock Axios, as illustrated in the snippet above. Here's how I am utilizing the mock in a test file:

```
// test-file.ts
import * as mocks from "@/_tests/mocks/mockAxios";
//... rest of the imports

describe("GET", () => {
    const mockData = [ { _id: '123', name: 'Client A' } ]

    it("should return a list of clients", async () => {
        mocks.mocks.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: mockData });
        //... rest of the test code
    })

})
```

I expected **`vi.mock`** to mock Axios successfully, allowing me to reuse mocks across different test files. However, I am confronted with a parse error at line 20 in **`mockAxios.ts`**.

**vitest version:** vitest/0.34.6.